# Better approach to generating and adding contents to files

Tags: shell-script, python, perl

I have an input file like below.

```
1 First one
2 First two
3 First three
3 Second three
```

I am generating 2 output files like below.

```
  #FILE1 
 1 First one
 2 First two
 3 First three
  #FILE2
 1 First one
 2 First two
 3 Second three
```

I have the below code which works perfectly fine for smaller inputs.

```sh
containsElement () {
  local e
  for e in "${@:2}"; do [[ "$e" == "$1" ]] && return 0; done
  return 1
}

declare -a InputIDs
touch file1.txt
while IFS=' ' read id value; do

             containsElement "$id" "${InputIDs[@]}"
             ret_val=$(echo $?)
             if [ "$ret_val" -eq 1 ]
             then
             #foreach file present in the directory, we need to add.
             for f in /home/ramesh/*; do
             echo "$id $value" >> $f;
             done
             else

             counter=0
             for f in /home/ramesh/*; do
             let counter=counter+1
             filename="$id.$counter"
             cp "$f" /home/ramesh/"$filename".txt
             sed -i '/^'$id'/d' /home/ramesh/"$filename".txt
             echo "$id $value " >> /home/ramesh/"$filename".txt
             done
```

The problem is the script takes almost 15 minutes to execute for inputs that have 50 values. (out of 50 values, 15 are repeated). For the 50 values, it generated **131,072** files which I believe are the total number of combinations possible for my input.

Is there a better approach to implement this?

EDIT:

A more complicated example is as below.

```
16250 somevalue in second column for all rows
16875 
17507 
17662 
18048 
18276 
18355 
20544 
23169 
158497 
160042 
163152 
163740 
164017 
164775 
165500 
166321 
166600 
166600 
166600 
166871 
167201 
169308 
169762 
169866 
170408 
171318 
171529 
171947 
173032 
174311 
174760 
177043 
177176 
177783 
177783 
177783 
177783 
177783 
177783 
177783 
177783 
177783 
177783 
177783 
177783 
177783 
177783 
177783 
177783
```

Comment: FWIW since this is a scripting/programming question, it's probably going to get migrated to Stack Overflow. You're better off asking there anyways. U&L is for platform-centric questions. "It works but how can I make my script more efficient" is purely a programming question.

Comment: Your example looks too simple given the description of the problem. Can you provide a slightly more complicated example? Might as well show us your full input too.

Comment: ok. But I always felt comfortable posting my questions here, as I got useful suggestions/comments in this site. That is the main reason, I posted the question here.

Comment: I have added the file which originally took me 15 minutes.

Comment: I strongly recommend to use assembler, it will speed up the computation approximately by `log(n!)`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: do you need to generate all possible combinations? That will always be slow :) However, you can do at least something by preprocessing. I wanted to suggest to use file descriptors, but for combinatorial number of files, that is obviously impossible.

Comment: Who fills InputIDs?

Comment: I get from my relational tables.

Comment: Perhaps I'm being dense today, but what is the relation between the input and the output files contents?

Comment: I am generating all the possible combinations for a given set of input. From the list of outputs, I am applying an algorithm to find out which file is the perfect fit for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in [TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr):

```
(defstruct item nil
  id
  fields)

(let* ((items (build             ;; build list procedurally: goes with (add ...) below
                (awk ((plusp nf) ;; have at least one field
                      (fconv i)  ;; convert id field [f 0] to integer
                      (add (new item id (first f) fields (rest f)))))))
       (pitems (partition-by .id items))
       (combinations [apply maprod list pitems]))
  (each ((c combinations)
         (n (range 1)))
    (with-stream (*stdout* (open-file (fmt "file-~,06d" n) "w"))
      (each ((i c)) ;; item in combination
        (put-line `@{i.id} @{i.fields}`)))))
```

Notes:

- The [awk](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-03D16283) macro is used to munge the input into fields.
- The [build](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-02ACB8CE) macro is used to build a list of `item` structures out of the fields.
- The [partition-by](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-000167DF) function groups the list of items into a list-of-lists, where the sublists consist of consecutive items sharing the same numeric ID.
- From these partitions, we generate combinations by applying these partitions to the Cartesian product mapping function [maprod](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-001B0395). The product combinations are mapped through `list` to just list them.
- After that, the task is just to iterate over the product combinations, together with an incrementing counter, and then dump each combination into a separate file. The files are named file-NNNNNN (six digits) to anticipate the case when there are over 130 thousand.